# Is there a 4 views merge?

Tags: git, merge, diff

Most of the tools do 3 views:

1. local
2. base-vs-remote-vs-local
3. remote

The problem is that the base view in the middle tries to highlight the changes from **both local and remote** and if these changes are massive they overlap a lot making it the base view unreadable.

So my question goes:

Is there a way to merge files using 4 views mode:

1. local
2. base-vs-local
3. base-vs-remote
4. remote

So that base-vs-local and base-vs-remote have their own views?

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate, what use would this be to you?  If you resolve the base-local and base-remote changes sepearately then couldn't there still be a conflict when you complete the merge?

Comment: Having base-local separately I can see clearly **what** needs to be moved to remote. Having base-remote separately I can see **where** in the remote they need to be moved to.

Comment: I am not resolving them separately, where did you get that from? I am looking at both base-vs-remote and base-vs-local instead of one base-vs-both. How does it make it separate?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any tools that do this in one big shared view (I do not like big shared views in the first place), but you can do it manually quite easily from the command line.

Let's look at a typical case:

```
$ git fetch
...
   1234567..fedcba9  feature/foo -> origin/feature/foo
...
$ git status
On branch feature/foo
Your branch and 'origin/feature/foo' have diverged,
and have 123 and 321 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

*Ugh, big merge or rebase required, time for diffs.  Let's see what they did since the merge base:*

```
$ git diff feature/foo...origin/feature/foo
```

*... and what I did since the merge base:*

```
$ git diff origin/feature/foo...feature/foo
```

There are several important things to note here:

- The three-dot syntax, `A...B`.  Normally—i.e., when not doing `git diff`—this syntax means that whatever Git command you're running uses `git rev-list` (or invokes its revision parser code directly, if it's in C) and is getting the *symmetric difference* set of commits: every commit that is reachable from `A` *or* `B`, but no commit that is reachable from both `A` *and* `B`.  For a typical pair of branch names that have a single merge base, this is all the commits on either "side" of the branch point, excluding the merge base itself and all earlier commits.  Graphically:

  ```
                A1 - A2 - A3   <-- A
              /
  ... - o - *
              \
                B1 - B2        <-- B
  ```

  In this case there are five selected commits in total, three on the `A` branch and two on the `B` branch.  The commit marked `*` is the merge base, and it and all previous commits (like the `o` before `*`) are on both branches.
- This syntax is not specific to remote-tracking branches, nor to local branches.  It works with *any* pair of identifiers that identify commits: branch names, tag names, `HEAD~10`, and so on.  It simply does a graph operation, computing several intermediate sets to find the symmetric difference:

  *S*<sub>A</sub> = ancestors(`A`)
        *S*<sub>B</sub> = ancestors(`B`)
        *S*<sub>*common*</sub> = *S*<sub>A</sub> AND *S*<sub>B</sub>

  result = (*S*<sub>A</sub> OR *S*<sub>B</sub>) - *S*<sub>*common*</sub>

  Note that—assuming there is exactly one merge base—the merge base of two branches is the newest (right-most, in the drawing) commit in the common subset *S*<sub>*common*</sub>.  If (as is the case in some complex DAGs) there are *multiple* merge bases, they are *all* in *S*<sub>*common*</sub> and hence are *all* removed from the symmetric difference result (this is generally what we want, but see below).
- With `git rev-list` or its clients, we typically want to know which "side" a commit comes from, so there is `--left-right`, which marks them.  See also `--cherry-mark`, `--left-only`, `--right-only`, `--cherry-pick`, and so on.

#### `git diff` uses the merge base

With `git diff`, however, the three-dot syntax is stolen for a different purpose.  Instead of computing a symmetric difference, it picks out the merge base: the commit marked `*` in our drawing.

The `diff` command set will only ever compare two items (two commits, one commit and the work-tree, one commit and the index, and so on).  The three-dot symmetric difference syntax is mainly useful for obtaining two (often large) commit lists, *S*<sub>A</sub>-*S*<sub>*common*</sub> and *S*<sub>B</sub>-*S*<sub>*common*</sub>.  We can feed such lists to `git log -p`, and this may be helpful when scrutinizing a large merge or rebase set (as in the original question), e.g., when we want to isolate *why* some particular change occurred.  With `git diff`, though, we are just going to compare *two specific commits*.

The obvious two to compare are the merge base and the tip of `A` (for one side of the merge), and the merge base and the tip of `B` (for the other side of the merge).  This is what the three-dot syntax does here: find the merge base, then compare with the right-hand item.  Hence `git diff B...A` compares the merge base commit (of `A` and `B`) with (the tip commit on) `A`.  Since the merge base of `B` and `A` is the same as the merge base of `A` and `B`, `git diff B...A` compares that same commit with (the tip of) `B`.

The results work best when there is a single merge base.  For complex DAGs with multiple merge bases, you just get one chosen at apparent-random.  (The `recursive` merge strategy picks *all* these merge bases and merges them first, then merges the resulting tree with the two branch tips.  Other Git commands, including `git diff` and `git merge-base`, generally just pick the first one that pops out of the merge-base-finding algorithm.<sup>1</sup>  Multiple merge bases are not that common, and ideally, when they do occur, they all have the same tree so that none of this matters, but it's worth keeping in mind.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It just occurred to me while writing this up that there is no formal guarantee that the merge base chosen for `A...B` is the same as the merge base chosen for `B...A`.  I *think* we get the same merge base, when there are multiple candidates, but if the algorithm is sensitive to the order in which we enter the two tip commits, we could conceivably pick two *different* commits, when the merge base set contains several.  Eventually, I will have to go look at the code, but right now I do not have enough time...